# Django - OneToOneField does not work - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userdetail

Tags: django

I am trying to extend the User model with this:

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Používateľ")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name} ({self.user.username}) / Celková hodnota všetkých objednávok používateľa: {self.total_value_of_users_orders} €"

    @property
    def total_value_of_users_orders(self):
        all_orders = Order.objects.all().filter(user=self.user, status__in=["NW", "WP", "PD", "IP", "ST", "DN"])
        total_value = 0
        for order in all_orders:
            total_value += order.total_value
        return total_value
```

However, when I try to access the `total_value_of_users_orders` property, it does not work:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
all_users = User.objects.all()

for u in all_users:
    u.userdetail.total_value_of_users_orders
```

it shows this exception:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userdetail.
```

What am I doing wrong? I expect all users to have the `total_value_of_users_orders` property which either returns 0 (if there are no Orders belonging to the given user) or the exact value (if there are Orders belonging to the given user).

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your user does not have a `userdetail` related one-to-one object in the database. You can create it when you need it or when you create a user.

There are several ways to handle it:

1. Creating UserDetail object immediately after creating user. This can be easily done using [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/). (You may need to modify generated migration to create UserDetail for old ones.) *It can be done in model manager too. Model manager is less problematic and easier to debug than signals. You can google known problems with signals.*
2. Creating UserDetail object (if doesn't exist) when you want to access it. You can implement it yourself or use [django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying/)'s AutoOneToOneField. *It would be introducing a side effect to a retriever though. It also sort of means leaving your model in an invalid state until the relationship is accessed. Always go for option 1 if the relationship is required.*
3. Checking if user has a `userdetail` or not (using `hasattr`) every time you want to access it. Read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). **This is the correct way to go if the relationship is nullable (optional, not required).** Only, it is ugly. It should have been as simple as `if user.detail`. So maybe it can be improved.

There are other options that may work much better if you can extend the User model, but it seems you already migrated it, so it won't be that easy.

In the end there is only two ways it can be: **one to one relationship is either required or optional**. if it is required, one shouldn't exist without the other. so they should be created together. if it is optional, it should be treated as nullable.

Comment: Thank you. While all the 3 answers were correct, I spent a bit more time with analyzing the providing solutions by you. I have ended up using signals and my app now creates a new `UserDetail` for every new user after they register themeselves.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check for existence first:

```
if hasattr(u, 'userdetail'):
    print(u.userdetail.total_value_of_users_orders)
```

Note that the following will still give you an `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error:

```
if u.userdetail:
    print(u.userdetail.total_value_of_users_orders)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use django signal to create UserDetail at the time of User creation so that each user will have its own UserDetail and query can access total_value_of_users_order

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# ... your models

def create_user_detail(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserDetail.objects.create(user=instance)

# ...
post_save.connect(create_user_detail, sender=User)
```